# App not visible for Samsung Tab in google Play

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-mobile, android-permissions

my manifest contains the following entries:

```
<supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

which of these "excludes" the Samsung Tab 2 (GT-P5110)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permission `android.permission.CAMERA` implies requirement of features `android.hardware.camera` **and** `android.hardware.camera.autofocus`. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 doesn't have autofocus. May be it is the reason.

[Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features)

Comment: The camera is required due to the integrated basrcode-scanner. So can/could/should I <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

Comment: Everywhere I read, it says that the camera has autofocus... if you launch the standard camera app, does it perform autofocus?

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem in before. I add `targetsdkversion` in manifest and rectified the problem. so try like this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Good luck.

Comment: added targedSdkVersion, no luck :-(